# FlowPlayer Commercial Does Not Load

Tags: javascript, flash, video-streaming

Since FlowPlayer does not offer support unless you pay for it, even on the commercial version, I'm asking this question here for I have to fork out money to fix this.

We're currently using the commercial version FlowPlayer Flash. I've downloaded the update for the plugin and updated the key. The key was gotten from the account page on FlowPlayer's site for domain in question.

I've tested the player on my local development server and it works as expected. With the key in place, it displays the FlowPlayer logo because the domain does not match. But when I deploy to the production server where the domain does match, it does not go past loading the swf file. The domain has the www while what is registered does not, but as I understand it, this does not matter since sub-domains are allowed with the FlowPlayer.

I've enabled the debugging and checked the network inspector in Chrome. On my development server I get a whole lot of debugging lines in the console and the movie plays. But on the production server, I'm only getting one line `$f.fireEvent ["onBeforeLoad"]`. The network inspector shows that the last thing loaded was the swf file... the movie is not requested.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<script src="videos/player/flowplayer-3.2.13.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div class="myPlayer"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
flowplayer(".myPlayer", "videos/player/flowplayer.commercial-3.2.17.swf", {
    key : '#$fa89c5fe302bc057b35',
    clip : {
        url : '/videos/3M_Command_Holiday_60_New_Agency_130814.f4v',
        scaling : 'orig',
        autoPlay : true,
        autoBuffering : true
    },
    debug: true,
    log : {
        level  : 'debug',
        filter : '*'
    }
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The page is in the public_html folder and I've tried relative and absolute links to video, js and swf files.

This exact video plays with the free version of the player and the now out dated commercial version we are using on the rest of the site. I've moved the plugin files for the new version into a separate folder from any other version incase it's a conflict of some sort.

Any assistance would be appreciated. Thanks